# Mediawiki's Navbox template not displaying boxes in personal wiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I'm using Mediawiki and am having trouble with the Navbox template working correctly. I exported the templates/modules and they seem to be working alright. When I use the following as an example:

```
{{Navbox
|name = Navbox/doc
|state = uncollapsed
|image = {{{image}}}
|title = {{{title}}}
|above = {{{above}}}
|group1 = {{{group1}}}
|list1 = {{{list1}}}
|group2 = {{{group2}}}
|list2 = {{{list2}}}
|list3 = {{{list3}}} ''without {{{group3}}}''
|group4 = {{{group4}}}
|list4 = {{{list4}}}
|below = {{{below}}}
}}
```

I get a string of text but no boxes.

[Output on my wiki](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slRRa.jpg)

I'm not sure if there has anything to do with $wgUseTide or if there is some CSS class issue I'm bumping up into. I'm also not that great with coding in general though I'm doing what I can. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Well, your inputs are empty and you are missing all the CSS. Wikipedia will have that on the page [`MediaWiki:Common.css`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Common.css)